# Python: Play Video file from a Buffer

Tags: python, video, tcp

I am working on a python program that receives broken chunks of video files over a TCP socket.
While receiving, I pull my data into a variable like:

```
film = sock.recv(100000)
```

What I am currently doing is writing this to a file 'received.mp4' and then playing it.

**Is there a way I could directly play this video from the `film` buffer?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can do that.

I'd use an external player and just feed the chunks to it's `stdin` like so:

```
# cmdline = ['vlc', '--demux', 'h264', '-'] #pick a media player
# cmdline = ['mplayer', '-fps', '25', '-cache', '1024', '-']
player = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    player.stdin.write(data)
```

(taken from http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/latest/recipes1.html#recording-to-a-network-stream )

You could also use a named pipe and write to that, or utilize some python bindings to your favourite video player.

Comment: This seems like a decent way to do it but I can't make it run on an mp4 video. Could someone please help with the VLC terminal options?

Comment: I just got it to work.
Setting `cmdline = ['vlc', '-']` lets VLC figure out the codec and stuff on its own I guess. And my video starting playing, with sound too!

Comment: I tried this code for microphone input (module pyaudio) with no success.